# What does もうやめてください mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

If someone says 「もうその呼{よ}び方{かた}をやめてください。」, does it mean:

1. Stop calling me that already.
2. Stop calling me that now.
3. Don't call me that anymore.

How do もう and やめる interact?

Answer (score 6):

やめる means 'to quit' so もうやめてください essentially means "please quit it" and もう emphasizes annoyance implying that someone has continued to do something much to one's repeating request of cessation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think it means the sentence 3. The usage of this もう is 4 in this dictionary and it means "anymore". http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218382/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86/

Other sayings of the sentence are もうそう呼ぶのをやめてください, もうそう呼ばないでください,etc.

By the way, could you teach me the meaning of "already" in "Stop calling me that already"?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The already in that context indicates impatience or annoyance. If i had to put it in words, it means "it has reached the point that I can no longer tolerate something." It is common in English in sentences like "I give up already!" or "Shut up already!" [http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/already] (See the third definition here. )

Comment: Then, what is the difference between 1 and 3 in your question?

Comment: Well, in English at least, "already" and "anymore" are fundamentally different words with different connotation, I think. I would say that 1 means "don't call me that" while expressing the speaker's annoyance that it has reached the present time and they are _still_ being called that. 3, on the other hand, simply means the speaker wants the listener to call them that no further.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

[Another explanation of もう from 大辞林.](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_mou_-070/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86/beginswith/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86/?itemid=DJR_mou_-070)

It seems that No. 1, 2, and 3 in goo国語辞書（from 大辞泉） correspond to No. 4, 2, and 3 in 大辞林. No. 4 and 5 in goo国語辞書 are variations of No. 1 in 大辞林 segmentalized with emotional contexts.

Comment: So in that case would you agree that "don't call me that anymore" is the best translation of もうその呼び方をやめてください?

Comment: @FinS "Don't call me that anymore" is just another way of saying "Stop calling me that", and neither proposed English sentence has a もう equivalent that I can see. In English I would use "I said stop calling me that." or "I said not to call me that anymore." "I said" expresses the frustration of having to repeat yourself. Mild swear words might be used for this purpose instead like "jeez" or "dammit", but if you translate a sentence this way you risk making the translated version sound too strong.

Comment: Then you think the one and only function of もう here is to impart emotion? What about when someone is being pestered and they say もう許してください, it is the same?

Comment: I say both are correct. You seem to know もう quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another possible meaning

> Enough Already!

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c0489fc3-fc41-40d8-8577-c16ea5b01d2c

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/dec0882f-7958-41f9-a04e-b3ba26b77a1f

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/0a697cc7-ae97-4932-beae-a3f0a872ff4d

https://vlipsy.com/vlip/zoolander-shutup-enough-already-ballstein-ANT48IkW

and similar phrases like

> Enough is Enough!

Said when someone wants someone else to stop with something annoying. For example arguing long past the point of needed to argue or going into too much details too long or just badgering someone too long etc ... Two kids having a stupid argument and the mom saying "ENOUGH ALREADY! If you two don't stop immediately you're grounded".

Is a common English phrase that もうやめなさい would generally fit. I suppose もうやめてください is slightly less blunt but still seems like it fits "Enough Already" depending on the situation and the way it's said. Maybe "Please, enough already" if speaker is annoyed but adds in the "please" just to make it less angry.

> ## enough already
>
> #### meaning:
>
> used for saying that you want something to stop
>
> #### Synonyms and related words:
>
> **Ways of telling someone to stop doing something**:
>    stop it/that, hands off, give something a rest...

- stop it! = enough already! (see above)
- stop it! = やめてください／やめなさい
- already = もう
- enough already!  = もうやめてください／もうやめなさい

This is one of many correct translations depending on the situation.

Note that it can be shorted to just Enough!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXyamiWqGA0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoW9mMJwIDQ

Comment: I think that's a weird way to say it by itself in English in many cases. For example in for the sentence in the question, it would be quite odd to say `enough already` instead of say `enough already with that name` or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

The speaker is expressing (with some exasperation) that they wish for the addressee to stop using a certain way of addressing them (i.e. a nickname).

As an example, if a childhood friend calls you by your nickname from a long time ago, you might say もうその呼び方をやめてください because you prefer a different nickname now. Another reason for wanting them to stop using that nickname is perhaps a change in your relationship that either made you closer or farther apart.

Somewhat literally:
もう [Already] その呼び方 [that way of calling (me)] をやめてください [Please stop]

I'd translate this as: "Please stop calling me that already."